# Database of English words pronunciation

Tags: data-request, language, english, audio

Is there any downloadable open database of English words pronunciation in audio format?

Answer (score 10):

[Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/) currently offers [more than 20.000 sound files with English pronunciation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aEnglish_pronunciation), around [1.500 of those with British English pronunciation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aBritish_English_pronunciation). All of them are published under an open license.

Unfortunately, there are currently [no dumps of the media files](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aContents) available. However, there is a page that explains [how to reuse the content outside of Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aReusing_content_outside_Wikimedia).

As an alternative, there is [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/). Their audio files are licensed under the more restrictive (and not entirely open-data-compliant) [CC BY-NC-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_GB). On the other hand, [they do offer an API](http://api.forvo.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [Project SHTOOKA](http://shtooka.net/index.php)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [Macmillan Dictionary API](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/tools/aboutapi.html) can help you

Comment: It is not open data.

Answer (score 1):

The [dump here](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html) contains nearly all pronunciation data used on the English wiktionary. So the files are from a combination of sources like project SHTOOKA, Lingualibre, etc.