# Audio Datasets Featuring Different Speakers Saying the Same Sentence (English)?

Tags: data-request, language, audio

Seeking a dataset of audio files consisting of recordings featuring different people saying the same sentence in English for deep neural network (DNN) training and testing.

Comment: Since this question has a bounty, it can't be flagged for close (and Laurent's answer here is a good one) but see also http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/looking-for-audio-data-set-for-english-words?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [speech accent archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/):

> uniformly presents a large set of speech samples from a variety of
>   language backgrounds.

As for English, [the following subset](http://accent.gmu.edu/browse_language.php?function=find&language=english) contains the sentences:

> Please call Stella.  Ask her to bring these things with her from the
>   store:  Six spoons of fresh snow peas, five thick slabs of blue
>   cheese, and maybe a snack for her brother Bob.  We also need a small
>   plastic snake and a big toy frog for the kids.  She can scoop these
>   things into three red bags, and we will go meet her Wednesday at the
>   train station.

It stands under a Creative Commons License. It is described in [The Speech Accent Archive: towards a typology of English accents](http://booksandjournals.brillonline.com/docserver/9789401206884_webready_content_s014.pdf), Steven H. Weinberger  and Stephen A. Kunath.

The [ELSDSR (English Language Speech Database for Speaker Recognition)](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~lfen/elsdsr/) is another choice. It is not so open directly, but [you can ask for the full version](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~lfen/elsdsr/index.php?page=avl). It contains voice messages from 22 speakers (12M/10F), and the age covered from 24 to 63. You can find [a few .wav on the example page](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~lfen/elsdsr/index.php?page=exp).

On a funnier note, requiring a little more work, [Peter Sellers Reads The Beatles’ “She Loves You” in 4 Different Accents](http://www.openculture.com/2016/03/peter-sellers-reads-the-beatles-she-loves-you-in-4-different-accents.html).